# Versioning and Diff in cq5 Publish Instance?

Tags: aem

In the Author Instance I can produce versions of my page by the sidekick.

sidekick is not available in the publish instance so I would like to ask if there is a way to profide this function in the publish instance.

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publish instance is where the 'live' content for your site is. There shouldn't be anything but the current live versions of your content on the publish instance. It is bad practice to have changes made on publish that have not gone through the author instance.

The author instance is where content versioning and authoring is managed. When the content is ready to go 'live' you replicate it to the publish instance.